# C# Minimal SQL Database

Tags: c#, database, sql

I'm working on a small project (not production) where I'm needing to store enough data that something like a CSV would be inefficient to process and an SQL/MySQL server would be too much. Does .Net have any way to efficiently store several entries of data with the ability to query without having to manage and connect to a server rather loading and processing a single file.

Comment: If you already have a database server up and running making another database on there is pretty trivial. If you are only using the data maybe you could consider Access.

Comment: @Brad this is just a personal project and I don't currently run any database servers at my home. Your suggestion of Access maybe exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm [not a fan of Access](https://www.google.com/search?q=microsoft+access+is+evil), but I'll grant it may the right solution sometimes.  Have you considered [Object Serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4475525/427192)?  Just create an object & write it to a file.  (The object could be a `List<foo>`)

Comment: Are you wanting these to persist or do they only need to be in-memory?

Comment: @DanPichelman Though each entry is small there will be ~4 Thousand so that may not be the best way to go.

Comment: @Richard Persist

Comment: @David: 4000 entries - so few? Why not hold them all in-memory? If you just need an in-memory database to make some queries, without any administrative tools, a dataset with some datatable (persisted to a file) may be enough for your needs.

Comment: [linqdb](https://github.com/ren85/linqdb)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few alternatives, in no particular order:

1. All versions of (paid?) visual studio come with [SQL Server Express installed](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx). You can use that.
2. (Ugh) [XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941928/best-way-to-store-data-locally-in-net-c)
3. [SQL Server CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) (basically, local SQL via file)
4. [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

More ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639846/what-is-a-good-embedded-database-to-use-with-c

Comment: I really want something that is totally self contained in a single executable, no DLLs and no third party software. Are any of the above, except XML, able to fit these needs?

Comment: You can embed the dlls in your executable maybe.

Comment: Well I guess the most important part is no third party *services such as MSSQL/MySQL would #3 or #4 fit that

Comment: I don't remember if SQL CE has a separate runtime or not.  SQLite doesn't, but it can be a little tricky to set up with a .NET project.

Comment: I would add that LocalDB is an option.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc

Comment: Would probably avoid SqlServerCe, as it's now considered as deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [the options Sklivvz offered](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/203459/4127), don't be afraid to venture outside of the SQL realm and use an embedded object-oriented database engine, such as [Sterling](http://sterling.codeplex.com/) or [DB4O](http://www.db4o.com/).

They offer the advantages of being small and file-based, embeddable into your application, but are also very fast and easy to program to.

Answer (score 3):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) would be your best option.
As written on their site:

> SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained,
>   serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine.

Seems really what you're looking for!

There's even a [Chocolatey package](http://chocolatey.org/packages/SQLite) if you're too lazy to download and install it yourself!

Answer (score 3):

ADO.NET can serialize to XML and has almost all of the functionality of an RDBMS.  (Well, the cheap ones, anyway.)

I know it's "Old" and looked down on, now, but ADO.NET works really well for exactly what you're describing.  It even does a pretty decent job of tracking non-committed changes.

It may be "Old," but it's certainly not "Busted."  It's got a fairly heavy memory footprint, though, so your call on that.  4000 records won't be an issue.

Comment: could you elaborate on "heavy memory footprint"?

Comment: @David - It means that the entirety of the dataset would be held in memory, and not just the records you return from a query.  If you had a database of 4 million records, holding it all in an ADO.NET dataset would be a serious draw on resources, whereas a "Real" RDBMS would hold it on a disk until you queried a subset of them.  4000 records is a small sneeze in memory usage, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: +1, I think this is the best option, for this requirements even something small as SQLlite seems to be much effort.